# Function not returning value when insort(lst,ele) is used

Tags: python

I am writing a simple collection abstraction in python using Bisect function. The problem here is that when I use insort function to add the data in the list, the function returns None. But when i use BISECT.BISECT(lst,ele), the function returns the value which would be the index of the list where the element could be inserted if desired.

```
# Python program to implement collection abstraction
# using Bisect Algorithm
# The program would add an element into the SORTED LIST"
# which would be the input
# The program would test whether the element is in the collection
# And also, to return the element of the collection if it is there

from bisect import bisect
from bisect import insort_right

the_list = []

def add(lst,ele):

    return insort_right(lst,ele)

#def test(lst,ele)

#def remove(lst,ele):


print("Enter the size of the list:")
N = int(input())

for x in range(N):

    x = input("")    
    the_list.append(x)
    the_list.sort()

print(the_list)

print("Enter the element to be added in the list")
element = input("")

add_element = add(the_list,element)
print("The element is added in collection at location:", add_element)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insort` doesn't return a value because it alters the list itself. Generally, Python functions that use side effects this way don't return values. If you want to return the modified list from `add`, do this:

```
def add(lst, ele):
    insort_right(lst, ele)
    return lst
```

But there's really no point in doing so, since the returned list is the same as the list that was passed in. The calling context already has access to that list, so there's no need to return it, and doing so is a bit unidiomatic.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am learning python through a book named exploring python by timothy budd. There is one exercise where the problem statement is to implement a collection abstraction using Bisect function. It has to implement the three function add(lst,ele) to add the element into the collection. Similarly, test(lst,ele) to return true if the element is in the collection;false otherwise.

Comment: So i assume that the problem is to implement a function in such a manner that calling add(lst,ele) from the command line must add the element in the sorted list without breaking or violating the sorting order of the list.

Comment: That sounds right to me. Fortunately, `insort` already does that for you, so the solution is built right in.